# Does one's t-shirt size correspond with the size of a "Perftzit" t-shirt style arba kanfos?

Tags: tzitzis

Does one's t-shirt size correspond with the size of a "Perftzit" t-shirt style arba kanfos?  For example, if one's t-shirt size is XL, would he also take an XL "Perftzit" t-shirt style arba kanfos?

Comment: Asking the manufacturer instead of us will probably get you better results

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](https://www.judaicaplace.com/content/980/tzitzis-page/) it has the sizing charts for adults and kids under the Perftzit brand.

The adult sizing is as follows:

[image]